# How to disable the checked effect in v-btn-toggle in Vuetify?

Tags: web, frontend, vuetify.js

I found the v-btn-toggle design pretty convenient and I decided to use it as a singular button (couldn’t find other solutions). I developed a button with the code below that satisfies my needs but once I click on it or the icon, the clicked part becomes greyed out.
How do I stop that from happening?

my code:

```
<v-btn-toggle
    class="custom-toggle-btn"
    divided
    variant="outlined"
>
    <v-btn                                      
        icon
        @click="handleDeleteButtonClick"
        class="custom-toggle-btn-icon"
    >
        <v-icon size="small" class="custom-toggle-btn-icon-icon">mdi-delete</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn
        @click="handleDeleteButtonClick"
        class="custom-toggle-btn-text"
    >
        <h4>Ignore</h4>
    </v-btn>
</v-btn-toggle>
```

with this styling

```
.custom-toggle-btn { /* Match the outlined variant's border color */
border: 1px white;
  border-radius:5%; /* Remove the button's border radius */
}
.custom-toggle-btn-icon {
    background-color: #22223b;
    color: #E7ECEF;
}

.custom-toggle-btn-text {
    background-color: #274C77;
    color: #E7ECEF;
}
.custom-toggle-btn:hover .custom-toggle-btn-icon {
    background-color: #274C77;
    color: #E7ECEF;
}

.custom-toggle-btn:hover .custom-toggle-btn-text {
    background-color: #22223b;
    color: #E7ECEF;
}
```

Tried changing the colors and disabling and even adding! Important but no good result.

Answer (score 0):

v-btn-toggle sets the button that was clicked last into an active state, which is the grey background you want to get rid off.

Just use a [`v-btn-group`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn-group/) if you don't want an active state:

```html
<v-btn-group divided variant="outlined">
  <v-btn icon="mdi-delete" />
  <v-btn >Ignore</v-btn>
</v-btn-group>
```

[playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: any idea on why it doesnt work in card component of Vuetify ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: if you put the button inside <v-card-actions> it will create a space between the 2 <v-btn> 
to undo that i had to put the buttons inside <v-card-item></v-card-item>

Comment: Interesting. The rule that creates the margin excludes v-btn-toggle, but not v-btn-group (`.v-card-actions .v-btn ~ .v-btn:not(.v-btn-toggle .v-btn)`). This is either a bug, or an indicator that they don't want card actions to look like a toolbar, but then it probably should add the left border to the buttons, too. Anyway, If you want to use v-card-actions, I guess you have to remove the left-margin with a CSS rule or add the `ml-0` class to each button.